# exceljs writes the file correctly in csv format, but the file is corrupted for xlsx format

Tags: node.js, express, xlsx, exceljs

This is my code for writing and downloading excel file using exceljs.

```
const excel = require('exceljs')
const tempfile = require('tempfile')

var workbook = new excel.Workbook()
var sheet1 = workbook.addWorksheet('sample')
sheet1.columns = req.keys // Some data

var tempFilePath = tempfile('.csv') 

workbook.csv.writeFile(tempFilePath).then(function() {

 res.download(tempFilePath, 'sample.csv', function(err) {
     if (err) {
       res.status(500).json({
         "success": false,
         "error": err
       })
       return
     }
 })

})
```

When i replace csv to xlsx, it writes but the file is corrupted.

```
const excel = require('exceljs')
const tempfile = require('tempfile')

var workbook = new excel.Workbook()
var sheet1 = workbook.addWorksheet('sample')
sheet1.columns = req.keys // Some data

var tempFilePath = tempfile('.xlsx') 

workbook.xlsx.writeFile(tempFilePath).then(function() {

 res.download(tempFilePath, 'sample.xlsx', function(err) {
     if (err) {
       res.status(500).json({
         "success": false,
         "error": err
       })
       return
     }
 })

})
```

Have attached the snapshots of it here.

[csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhluX.png) | [Unreadable image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHHYt.png) | [Corrupted image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMkfF.png) | [Postman response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvCH1.png)

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `Content-Type` header:

```js
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
```

CSV file's format is raw text, so it is easy to read without caring about MIME type. xlsx format is more complicated. If you don't set the content-type, the browser won't know what to do with the file

Comment: res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')

    res.download(tempFilePath, 'sample.xlsx', function(err) {
        if (err) {
          res.status(500).json({
            "success": false,
            "error": err
          })
          return
        }
    })

Comment: Nevermind, I tried to use your code, and it worked. The Content-Type is detected automatically. I think something wrong with your MS Excel app (old version, maybe). Try open file by Google Sheets or Office 360 then

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Hope this helps you.
If you download this excel file from the server side (In my case Node JS). 
The problem is solved by one line on the client side:  **req.responseType = "arraybuffer";**

```
requestData(req, "exportToExcel")
            .then(resXHR => {
                // For the correct processing of data from the server, you must specify the format/structure of data transfer
                resXHR.responseType = "arraybuffer"
                // Wait until the data is downloaded from the server
                resXHR.onload = function () {
                    // Call a modal window for saving with type and file name 
                    saveAs(new Blob([resXHR.response], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' }), 'users.xlsx')
                }
            })
```